# Fetching Data in React using Hooks with axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm new to web development and react. I have a problem about rendering after getting data from server. The server does give me back the data successfully but I can not render it out. In my case, name and id are not displayed.

When I log it out,

```
[]
[]
{status: "success", product: {…}}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rsFW.png
The data got from server contain a status message, and a product object.

How do I avoid empty fetching in the first and second row?
is it the correct way to fetch data from server like this way?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import './Payment.css';
import axios from 'axios';

function Payment(props) {
    const [productData, setProductData] = useState([]);
    const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false);

    const { name, id } = productData;

    const getProductData = () => {
        const productId = props.match.params._id;
        axios.get(`http://localhost:3000/api/v1/products/${productId}/payment`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data);
                setProductData(res.data);
            }, error => {
                console.log(error);
                setHasError(true);
            });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        getTourData();
    }, []);


    return (
        //render nothing
        <div>{id}</div>
        <div>{name}</div>

    )
}

export default Payment;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue in your code. That's the expected behaviour. Please note that hooks are called after the first render. Also network requests are asynchronous which means you will not receive the response immediately. Ideally you should handle three scenarios.

1. Loading/fetching
2. No data
3. Error

`const { name, id } = productData;` 
This line is incorrect. ProductData is an array. You should map over it.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
<div>{productData.id}</div>
<div>{productData.name}</div>
```

Because useState is watching for productData, not name and id. Notice how you define them:

```
const { name, id } = productData;
```

One more thing, is productData an array or object? Initial state is [] but later you are extracting name and id from it like it is an object:

```
const { name, id } = productData;
```

Comment: I still get the error saying that `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: can you provide a console.log() of productData?

Comment: I just attach an image in the question description.

Answer (score 0):

Before you try to access `id` and `name` which are obtain by destructuring `productData` You should check if `productData` contains some data.

And you don't have to do destructuration as varibales `name` and `id` are not coupled to their reference in the `productData` state. So when the value of `productData` state change that variable won't update to reference to the new value in the `productData`.

With all that said you can stick with the `productData` state without any destructuration and check if is not empty before rendering any view to the DOM.

```
let output = productData? <>
        <div>{productdata.name}</div>
        <div>{productdata.id}</div>
    </>: <div>No data available</div>;

return output;
```